# Missing firebase api ? how can i fix it?

Tags: firebase, arduino

In file included from C:\Users\Mypc\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src/FirebaseArduino.h:22:0,

```
             from
```

C:\Users\Mypc\Documents\Arduino\Pj\Firebase\Firebase.ino:3:

C:\Users\Mypc\Documents\Arduino\libraries\firebase-arduino-master\src/Firebase.h:26:25: fatal error: ArduinoJson.h: No such file or directory

#include

```
                     ^
```

compilation terminated.

exit status 1
Error compiling for board Generic ESP8285 Module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ArduinoJson library needs to be installed. From https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-arduino:

> FirebaseArduino now depends on ArduinoJson library instead of containing it's own version of it. Please either use Library Manager or download specific version of the library from github. We recommend that ArduinoJson is at least version 5.13.1

Note that the latest version of ArduinoJson is [not compatible](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-arduino/issues/358) with FirebaseArduino so you should stick to the 5.13.x release.